# Is it possible to flatten this particular sequence in scala?

Tags: scala, flatten

I have this structure:
`Seq[(Int, mutable.Set[List[A]])]`
and my aim is flatten it in order to obtain a structure like `List[List[A]]`.

In particular, my structure is something like this:
`val order = List((1,HashSet(List('o'))), (4,HashSet(List('i', 'j', 'k', 'l'))), (3,HashSet(List('a', 'b', 'c'), List('f', 'g', 'h'))), (2,HashSet(List('d', 'e'), List('m', 'n'), List('z', 'x'))))` and i want to obtain something like `val order = List( List('o'), List('i', 'j', 'k', 'l'), List('a', 'b', 'c'), ...)`.

I tried to make a `map` in this way:

```
order map {
      case (_, Set[List[A]]) => List[A]
}
```

but it doesn't work. The error is "pattern type is incompatible with expected type". 
The same thing also happens with:
`case (Seq[(_, Set[List[A]])]) => List[A]` and `case (Seq[(_, mutable.Set[List[A]])]) => List[A]`.

I'm pretty sure that to do the flattening, the solution is to use the map (or flatMap), but apparently I'm using it in the wrong way. Anyone have any suggestions / ideas of how I could do it? Thanks!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Your solution returns: ```List(List(o), List(i, j, k, l), List(a, b, c, f, g, h), List(d, e, m, n, z, x))```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
order.flatMap(_._2)
```

Comment: Yes, @Tim. Your solution is correct. but with a ```.toList``` 
to return the type ```List[List[A]]``` instead a ```Seq[List[A]]```

Comment: @ElidorDD The `order` in the example is already a `List` so `toList` is not necessary.